# Writing results to .xls (Submit 2 queries to webpage, and store different results into .xls)

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup, xlwt

I am using Python 2.76 to submit queries to an .aspx webpage and pick up the results by BeautifulSoup, and want to store them into an Excel spreadsheet.

```
import mechanize
import re
import xlwt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet('Legi', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

for items in ['university student', 'high school student']:

    url = r'http://legistar.council.nyc.gov/Legislation.aspx'
    request = mechanize.Request(url)
    response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
    forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
    form = forms[0]
    response.close()

    form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearch'] = items
    
    submit_page = mechanize.urlopen(form.click())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(submit_page.read())
    aa = soup.find_all(href=re.compile('LegislationDetail'))
    for bb in aa:
        cc = bb.text

        #print cc
        results = []
        results.append(cc)

    for row, legi_no in enumerate(results):
      sheet.write (row, 0, legi_no)

book.save("C:\\legi results.xls")
```

It finds and pick up the results, if I print the variable ‘cc’. however the writing into Excel spreadsheet is not successful because it only writes the first cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the `results` variable inside the `for bb in aa` loop.

This means `results` will get initialized to `[]` for each value in `aa` and in the end results will contain only one element (the last one), which is ofcourse not intended.

Put the `results` outside and it should work fine, as shown below.

```
import mechanize
import re
import xlwt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet('Legi', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

for items in ['university student', 'high school student']:

    url = r'http://legistar.council.nyc.gov/Legislation.aspx'
    request = mechanize.Request(url)
    response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
    forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
    form = forms[0]
    response.close()

    form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearch'] = items

    submit_page = mechanize.urlopen(form.click())
    soup = BeautifulSoup(submit_page.read())
    aa = soup.find_all(href=re.compile('LegislationDetail'))

    results = [] # Initialize results here !!!
    for bb in aa:
        cc = bb.text

        #print cc
        results.append(cc)

    for row, legi_no in enumerate(results):
      sheet.write (row, 0, legi_no)

book.save("C:\\legi results.xls")
```